# Decode extracted expression prior to populating into a struct

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-qi

I am trying to create a `boost::spirit::qi` parser that will populate a struct from an 'encoded' string. The content of the string is ascii hex data, but the fields I need to extract are not necessarily byte aligned.

I've created a trivial example where I do something similar, extracting a string and populating select character from the string into a struct. A more complex decode is needed for the final version, but this demonstrates the general idea.

My parser. I've bound a hex string parser to a semantic action that constructs the struct.

```
template <typename Iterator>
struct MyDataParser : qi::grammar<Iterator, MyData()>
{
    static MyData ExtractMyData( const std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >& val)
    {
        return MyData(val.at(0), val.at(3), val.at(6));
    }

    MyDataParser() : MyDataParser::base_type( decode_rule )
    {
        using namespace qi::labels;
        auto data_string = qi::repeat(8)[qi::xdigit];

        decode_rule %=
            data_string[ boost::phoenix::bind(&ExtractMyData,_1) ]
            ;
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, MyData()> decode_rule;
};
```

Struct declaration. Two constructors were necessary to get this to compile.

```
struct MyData
{
    char first_char;
    char fourth_char;
    char seventh_char;

    MyData(char first = 0, char fourth = 0, char seventh = 0)
        : first_char(first), fourth_char(fourth), seventh_char(seventh) {}

    MyData( const std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >& val)
        : first_char(val.at(0)), fourth_char(val.at(3)), seventh_char(val.at(6)) {}
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    MyData,
    (char, first_char)
    (char, fourth_char)
    (char, seventh_char)
)
```

However, this seems like a bit of a hack. Is there a built-in mechanism to do this that will support qi error handling? Ideally, the ctor would be called directly instead of the semantic action.

**Edit - Let me clarify what I am shooting for**

seh did a good job answering my question, but I didn't communicate the full scope.

1) I want to decode a hex string using a conversion function.
2) Do the above with a parser that is not coupled to a struct.

In a perfect world, I would have a final top-level rule that looks something like this:

```
auto rule %= char_
          << int_
          << hex_str_parser
          << repeat(8)[char_]
          ;
```

This would populate into a struct that is defined similar to this:

```
struct MyData {
    char my_char;
    int my_int;
    unsigned my_hex_value1;  // extracted vai hex_str_parser
    unsigned my_hex_value2;  // extracted vai hex_str_parser
    unsigned my_hex_value3;  // extracted vai hex_str_parser
    std::string my_string;
};
```

How can I define a rule that extracts content from an embedded string according to customized rules AND fits into another parser seamlessly?

Comment: "The content of the string is ascii hex data, but the fields I need to extract are not necessarily byte aligned"  - so what /do/ you need? You mean it's still aligned, but at 4-bit boundaries?

Comment: @sehe - The final problem I am trying to solve is this: I'll be receiving a hex string that represents binary data, and I need to extract certain bits. For example, the string "DEADBEEF" will need to be converted to a uint32_t, and a mask applied to get certain bits out.

Comment: You accidentally still said "how" you wanted to do it, instead of "what". And you'll need to be more specific (will it always be 8 characters? Will you need single bits, or 4-bit nibbles etc.)

Comment: I'm trying to keep the problem as generic as possible. What I need to do is this: convert ascii hex from a string into a tuple containing multiple values. Converting from the ascii string to a bitset and apply a mask is easy (and outside the scope of this question). I got stuck trying to return multiple values from a single parser. The closest I got was this. HTH

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look to me as though you use any automatic attribute propagation here. Therefore, you can do without the BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_* helpers¹.

`MyData` is an aggregate² so you don't need that constructor, if you don't want it. `MyData{'a', '2', 'e'}` is [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

Finally, I'd use a `phoenix::function` to make the semantic action prettier:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98ecbf78fe715d2e)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

struct MyData { char first_char, fourth_char, seventh_char; };

template <typename Iterator>
struct MyDataParser : qi::grammar<Iterator, MyData()>
{
    MyDataParser() : MyDataParser::base_type(start)
    {
        using namespace qi;
        start = repeat(8)[xdigit] [_val = _decode(_1)];
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, MyData()> start;

    struct DecodeF {
        MyData operator()(const std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >& val) const {
            return { val.at(0), val.at(3), val.at(6) };
        }
    };
    boost::phoenix::function<DecodeF> _decode;
};

int main() {
    std::string const input = "12345678";

    MyData data;
    if (qi::parse(input.begin(), input.end(), MyDataParser<std::string::const_iterator>(), data))
        std::cout << data.first_char << ":" << data.fourth_char << ":" << data.seventh_char << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
1:4:7
```

¹ besides, they were old fashioned. C++11 allows `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(MyData, first_char, fourth_char, seventh_char)`
² in fact, it's POD in this case

Comment: This is a great improvement on my initial try. Thanks! However, I was hoping that I could use the parser in a nested fashion - ie - it would take the string and return a tuple that could then be nested in other parsers.

Comment: What does it mean to "nest a tuple in other parsers". Or you mean "a parser (that would take a string and return a tuple) that could be nested" - this is already that.

Comment: IIUC - qi is converting each rule to a fusion-based tuple that allows mulitiple parsers to return data in a common container. I'd prefer not to be married to the MyData struct, but have a parser that returns the generic container. (This is what I meant when I mentioned 'built-in mechanisms' and 'error handling' in the original question. In hindsight, that wasn't particularly clear)